# Effeciently and atomically exchange two files in Windows

Tags: c#, winapi

My naive solution to maintain atomicity is to open streams on both files and exchange the contents via a temporary file. However, I understand that File.Move is much more efficient when both files exist on the same drive because no data is actually copied.

Unfortunately, C#'s File.Move requires that the destination file not exist, so it is impossible to use for an atomic exchange of two files.

Is there a way to ensure neither file will be touched during the exchange and still gain the efficiency of renaming files that exist on the same drive.

Preferably, I'm looking for a solution with C#, though I'm not against using a P/Invoke if there is a lower level way to achieve this. My understanding is that OSX can achieve this via exchangedata() and Linux can achieve this via renameat2(). Anything similar for Windows?

Comment: Have you looked at TxF? That would work.

Comment: You also could open both files exclusively and then use low level APIs to rename, then close the handles. Renaming actually is done on handles, not on paths.

Comment: I did consider TxF except Microsoft now "strongly encourages you to consider alternatives" since TxF seems to be on its way out.
Is there a way to work with handles from C# or will I need to do everything through a low level API?

Comment: PInvoke only, maybe you need to use the NT API.

Comment: The only way I could find to make changes via a file handle is using NT API's SetFileInformationByHandle. Unfortunately this method either overwrites existing files or errors when a file is in the way, making it about as useful as File.Move.

Comment: Use procmon.exe to trace NT level APIs. Try the ReplaceFile API and see what it does under the hood.

Comment: What atomicity guarantees do you need?  I think the usual approach would be to move both files to a temporary folder somewhere and then move them back.  You could open them while they are in the temporary folder (with a sharing mode of 0) if you need to ensure nobody else has them open before exchanging them.

Comment: Btw, I'm really not sure that they are going to remove the TxF API. For compatibility reasons that's unlikely. Also, I think Windows Update is a consumer of that API.

Comment: I think TxF could go because it's not widely used. I don't think there's any way to swap files atomically. File systems don't offer that sort of transaction control typically.

Comment: @Harry Johnston I was hoping to make sure the files could not be opened while I was moving them. This included the files I am working with and their destinations (which would cause an IO Exception). I will stick to using File.Move to a temporary location. Could still get an IO exception if someone sneaks a File.Open in mid step but I guess there is a reason we call asynchronous solutions "cooperating".

Comment: @usr Could be but Microsoft is being unusually clear about this point. "Microsoft strongly recommends developers utilize alternative means to achieve your application’s needs" [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968806(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Both OSX [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/exchangedata.2.html) and Linux [link](http://lwn.net/Articles/592952/) seem to disagree with you.

Comment: @eisenpony yeah, I wonder why this is. TxF is actually a fantastic help given the ridiculous fragility of filesystems.

Comment: In UNIX it is traditional to use the mere existence of a file (or more generally the structure of the directory tree) as a lock, so they need functions that manipulate the directory tree atomically.  That paradigm isn't commonly used in Windows.

Comment: If you want transactions and atomicity, use a database.

Comment: @usr: I don't think TxF affects the robustness of the file system itself.  If the file system is corrupted, there's no guarantee TxF will work at all, much less bypass or repair the corruption.

Comment: @HarryJohnston NTFS is 100% robust against corruption (barring bugs and hardware issues). What I mean is that FS guarantees are so weak, complicated and esoteric that it's hard to program against. TxF cleans that up.

Comment: @usr, never mind then, I'm afraid I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Not a direct solution and it will not be really atomic this way, but at least you could ensure a consistent state, if you extend the described method to multiple files: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adioltean/2005/12/28/how-to-do-atomic-writes-in-a-file/